# How to Replace Middle String to Other character in Dart?

Tags: string, flutter, dart

```
final email = 'abcdefghij@email.com';
final phoneNumber = '0123456789';
```

This email string convert to  this patter like
**Fox Example**

> email ->  **ab****j@email.com**
> phoneNumber ->  **(012)3****89**

Please help using *RegExp* and 0ther technics are most welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way

```
void main() {
  
var result = 'nilesh.rathod@gmail.com'.replaceAll(new RegExp('(?<=.)[^@](?=[^@]*?[^@]@)'), '*');
print(result);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [replaceRange](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/String/replaceRange.html) method

```
final email = 'abcdefghij@email.com';
final phoneNumber = '0123456789';

final hiderPlaceholder = "****";

final censuredEmail = email.replaceRange(2, email.indexOf("@")-1, hiderPlaceholder);
  
final censuredPhoneNumber = "(" + phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + ")" + phoneNumber.substring(3).replaceRange(1, phoneNumber.substring(3).length-2, hiderPlaceholder);
  
print (censuredEmail);
print (censuredPhoneNumber);
```

[image: code with replaceRange]

Or you can just go for the evergreen substring

```
final email = 'abcdefghij@email.com';
final phoneNumber = '0123456789';

final hiderPlaceholder = "****";

final censuredEmail = email.substring(0, 2) + hiderPlaceholder + email.substring(email.indexOf("@")-1);

final censuredPhoneNumber = "(" + phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + ")" + phoneNumber.substring(3, 4) + hiderPlaceholder + phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length-2);

print (censuredEmail);
print (censuredPhoneNumber);
```

[image: Censured phone and censured phone number]

P.s. obviously, add all the controls you want, e.g. for the length of the email/phone number